# SSIS Alternatives to one-by-one update from RecordSet

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I'm looking for a way to speed up the following process: I have a SSIS package that loads data from Excel files on a weekly basis to SQL Server. 
 There are 3 fields: ***Brand, Date, Value***.
 
In the dataflow, I check for existing combinations of ***Brand+Date***, and new combinations go to the table directly, the existing ones go to a RecordSet destination for updates:
 
 
[image: DataFlow1]

The next step is to update the Value of the existing combinations: 
 
[image: DataFlow2]

As you can see, there are thousands of records to update, and it takes too long. The number of records tend to grow week by week. Please suggest.

Comment: You could use the MERGE operator and perform a merge of the data, when matched the MERGE will update, otherwise it will insert a new record. However, this requires the two sets of data to be sorted out before merging and the SORT will also take some time. 

You could try and check the performance.

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way will be do this inside a Stored procedure using [`ELT (Extract Load Transform)`](http://www.jamesserra.com/archive/2012/01/difference-between-etl-and-elt/) approach.

1. Push all data from excel as is into a table(called load to a staging table in theory). Since you do not seem to be concerned with data validation steps, this table can be a replica of final destination table columns.
2. Next step is to call a stored procedure using <kbd>Execute SQL</kbd> task. Inside this procedure you can put all your business logic. Since this steps with native data manipulation on SQL server entities, it is the fastest alternative.
3. As a last part, please delete all entries from the staging table.

You can use indexes on staging table to make the SP part even faster.

Comment: So pull all data that would go to the RS, correct? Replace the RS destination with another OLEDB destination to a STG table. And then do the update via SP.. I am going to try this one and let you know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to have staging table in the database instead of recordset as the staging table would not have issue with large data. You can delete it before every use or after and basically it will serve the same purpose but your package won't fail on the bigger volume of data.